# Has anyone configured SMTP relay for Outbound Emails in G Suite?

Tags: email, smtp, bitnami, google-workspace, canvas-lms

Has anyone been able to route outgoing mail through Google using another non-Gmail SMTP service?

I currently have a website running with Bitnami vm running a CanvasLMS application on a Google Cloud Platform server.

When entering my GSuite Gmail Advanced Settings, the required steps have been done to configure the SMTP relay service. (TLS set to true)

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en&authuser=3&ref_topic=2921034

I have also configured the setup for the outgoing email server at /apps/canvaslms/htdocs/config/outgoing_mail.yml (replacing username and password with my application's credentials)

```
production:
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  address: smtp-relay.gmail.com
  port: 587
  user_name: USERNAME@gmail.com
  password: PASSWORD
  authentication: plain        # plain, login, or cram_md5
  domain: smtp-relay.gmail.com
  outgoing_address: USERNAME@gmail.com
  default_name: CANVAS LMS
```

Saved the changes and restarted the server. When trying to send an email in Canvas for new user registration, it never reaches the receivers email inbox.

I have reviewed my application logs and have not discovered any errors related to this

Any thoughts on troubleshooting this SMTP issue???

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/canvaslms/configuration/configure-smtp/
https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Question-Forum/emails-are-not-sent-to-users-students/m-p/230561#M128347

Comment: Most likely, G Suite is rejecting your authentication. Depending on how you have PHP configured for error logging, you will find details in one of the log files (syslog, php_error.log, etc). On most systems, there are two `php.ini` files. One for Apache and the other for the PHP CLI. You need to review the Apache `php.ini`. The function `phpinfo()`  will report the location of `php.ini`.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the tip! After editing the php.ini file to allow for logs and defining the php error log path. I created a php error log file and gave the appropriate read and write permissions, restarted the server, sent some emails and not seeing any errors in the php error log. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you turn on debugging?

Comment: @JohnHanley is that configuration done in php.ini or elsewhere?

Comment: PHP logging is configured in `php.ini`. Your library might also have options. https://rollbar.com/guides/where-are-php-errors-logged/